# Валидация полей django

Tags: python, django, валидация

Сломал всю голову, перечитал кучу документации, но так и не понял, что сделать валидацию полей. Можете натолкнуть на путь истинный?

view.py

```
def addAccess(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    frm = AccessesForm(data=request.POST)
    if frm.is_valid():
        title = request.POST.get('title')
        service = request.POST.get('service')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        comment = request.POST.get('comment')

        Accesses.objects.create(title=title, service=service,
                                username=username, password=password, 
                                comment=comment, owner=request.session['username'])

    frm = AccessesForm()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class AccessesForm(forms.Form):
   title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
   service = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
   username = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
   password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
   comment = forms.CharField(max_length=150)


   def clean(self):
      cleaned_data = super(AccessesForm, self).clean()
      title = cleaned_data.get('title')
      # service = cleaned_data.get('service')
      # message = cleaned_data.get('message')
      if len(title) < 5:
          raise ValidationError('Title should be more 5 characters')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Accesses(models.Model):

id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
service = models.CharField(max_length=100)
username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
comment = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
owner = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

view.py

```
def addAccess(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    frm = AccessesForm(data=request.POST)
    if frm.is_valid():
        title = frm.cleaned_data['title']
        service = frm.cleaned_data['service']
        username = frm.cleaned_data['username']
        password = frm.cleaned_data['password']
        comment = frm.cleaned_data['comment']

        Accesses.objects.create(title=title, service=service,
                                username=username, password=password,
                                comment=comment, owner=request.session['username'])

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    else:
        frm = AccessesForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'accessForm': frm})
```

Comment: Не используйте `request.POST['чтототам']`, всё что вам нужно уже есть внутри `frm` https://www.djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/forms/index.html

Comment: Исправил, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def clean_title(self):
# Одно поле
    title = self.cleaned_data.get('title', '')
    if len(title) < 5:
          raise ValidationError('Title should be more 5 characters')
    retutn title

def clean(self):
# Вся форма
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    # ...
    return cleaned_data
```

И после `form.is_valid()` лучше получать данные через `field = form.cleaned_data['field_name']`

```py
def addAccess(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        frm = AccessesForm(data=request.POST)
        if frm.is_valid():
            title = frm.cleaned_data['title']
            service = frm.cleaned_data['service']
            username = frm.cleaned_data['username']
            password = frm.cleaned_data['password']
            comment = frm.cleaned_data['comment']

            Accesses.objects.create(title=title, service=service, username=username, password=password, comment=comment,
                                owner=request.session['username'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'accessForm': frm})  
   return render(request, 'index.html', {'accessForm': AccessesForm()})
```

Comment: С этим вроде разобрался. Главная проблема заключается в выводе ошибок в этой ж форме при submit

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести в форму ошибки
Знаю, что нужно рендерить новую форму уже с ошибками, но как сделать не знаю

Comment: @NikitaTarasov, создавать новую форму не нужно, отдавайте в шаблон ту же форму, что получили в этой строке `frm = AccessesForm(data=request.POST)`, в ней уже будут ошибки

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но у меня уже валидация перед глазами бегает, не могу сообразить, изменил вопрос, добавил code view.py, там обработчик сабмита, что в нем не так?

Comment: @NikitaTarasov, поправила ответ

Comment: Сработало, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
class AccessesForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(min_length=5, max_length=50)
    ...
```

В [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#charfield) написано, что в этом случает будет использоваться [`MinLengthValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.MinLengthValidator), который вызовет `ValidationError`, если длина меньше указанной.

Comment: Я пока тренируюсь просто. Про эту вещь в курсе. Мне нужно кастомить валидатор. В ответе ниже сказано, как сделать валидатор, с этим разобрался. но как вывести ошибки, я не понимаю до сих пор